# R: Heteroskedasticity and Autocorrelation Consistent Covariance Matrix Estimator for panel linear model with fixed effects

Tags: r, plm, hac

Is there a way for generating Heteroskedasticity- and autocorrelation-consistent (HAC) standard errors for panel linear model with two fixed effects?

I came across `vcovHAC` but it only seems to work for linear model.

Comment: `plm::vcovHC` in package `plm` is what you want.

Comment: Can you be more specific please ? Because I read the manual and I don’t think so. HAC for two fixed effects, does not work well with the options provided in the package (HC1, HC2 etc.)

Comment: If you estimate 2-way FE model with `plm`, `plm::vcovHC` is what you likely want. The package brings its own function to estimate robust variance-covariance matrices, see `?plm::vcovHC`.